# Counter for the Theorem and Lemma

Tags: numbering, theorems

In an article, I need the counter for Theorems (Lemmas), like **Theorem X.Y**. But, somewhere I do not need the counter for the Theorems, for example: in preface/appendix or somewhere else like **Theorem**.

**Q**: How to define the environment for the Theorem or Lemma.

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? An tell us what **X** and **Y** should be?

Comment: @samcarter **X.Y** means the counting number associated to the section/chapter. i.e. **Theorem 1.2**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) you can define a new theorem environment using

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
```

If you want an unnumbered version similar to this, then use

```
\newtheorem*{theorem*}{Theorem}
```

Use the `theorem*` environment inside the preface or appendix, and `theorem` elsewhere. Here is a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem*{theorem*}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
This is a numbered theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem*}
This is an unnumbered theorem.
\end{theorem*}

\end{document}
```